# Unable to deploye ejb3 project on eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I am developing an EJB 3.0 application on eclipse mars. I am unable to deploy project on glassfish 4 server. I use JDK 7.

My server log:

```
cannot Deploy SampleEJBProject
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [SampleEJBProject] : A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.weld-integration [296]], State = [RESOLVED]
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.weld.WeldContainer
    name=org.glassfish.weld.WeldContainer
    contracts={org.glassfish.weld.WeldContainer,org.glassfish.api.container.Container}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=Bundle-SymbolicName={org.glassfish.main.web.weld-integration},Bundle-Version={4.1.1}
    rank=0
    loader=OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.HK2Loader(OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.weld-integration [296]], State = [RESOLVED],377949866)
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=414
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=2094253683
    reified=false)
. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Please help me.
I am referring this link for developing application

https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/javaee/myeclipse-ejb-3-x-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved automatically.